# postgres vacuum cleaning for long running sessions

Tags: postgresql

Say a transaction started on day1 updating table1, another transaction starts on day2 updating table2. On day3 they both keep running, there is a table3 on which dml's are happening and dead records are getting created and when vacuum is run, it wont do any cleanup for dead tuples created since day1 in table3 because of the long running transaction from day1 - right?

Now say day1 transaction completes, and day2's transaction still keeps running on day3 - if vacuum is run on table3, does it cleanup any dead records created on day1 and keep dead records created on day2? or does it keep all the dead records until the day2 transaction completes. My hunch is former, please confirm.